# C# modified custom control wont update in designer

Tags: c#, .net, controls, designer

I created a control that inherits the TreeView control.  In this new control I've added a property.  I've added this new control to my design just fine.  Everything works.  However, when I edit the code of this new control and build, it updates in the toolbox, but not in the design.  The only way I've found to update my design is to physically drag a new instance of the control into the designer and reconfigure it from scratch.  Is there a way to tell Visual Studio to update instances to match what is in the toolbox?     I

Comment: Try closing and reopening the designer window, maybe?

Comment: The design-time rendering code has to be re-executed after it has been rebuilt.  Have you tried closing the form and reopening it, or restarting VS?

Comment: I've closed everything, restarted VS, restarted my computer, cleaned both projects in my solution, rebuilt both projects in my solution... nothing updates.

Answer (score 0):

It will not be updated in the designer unless, you rebuild your project. Close the designer where it is hosted and re-open it after building.